# Position frame on top of button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, click, position

I will be creating a custom control where a frame is positioned on top of a button, all within a grid. When I do this and the button is clicked, the button ends up on top and the frame disappears. How do I keep the frame on top when the button is clicked?

Here is the simple xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Text="Test"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        TextColor="White"/>
    <Frame 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        CornerRadius="12"
        HasShadow="false"
        OutlineColor="Transparent"
        BackgroundColor="Red"
        Padding="0">
        <Label Text="3" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10"/>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I am trying to create a button with a badge. The badge isn't positioned well here, but I'm just concerned about the behavior of the badge being hidden when the button is clicked.

Comment: a screenshot illustrating what you're trying to do would help.  Generally hiding clickable elements under non-clickable elements seems like a strange approach

Comment: Can you please share more code and details about what you want to achieve? From your shared code snippet, the frame won't disappear when the button is clicked.

Comment: I was planning on creating a button with a badge. There is no other code to share other than wrapping the Grid in a ContentPage. There is no code-behind or ViewModel code right now. I'm just trying to understand whether I can keep another control on top of a button. The frame does disappear when the button is clicked.

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

> The frame does disappear when the button is clicked

Your code works well on iOS and there is a known issue in Android:[Content rendered above a Material button is not visible when button is pressed](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7300)

Just add the following to your `MainActivity.OnCreate` before the `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState)` call:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("UseLegacyRenderers");
```

Refer: [Button in a AbsoluteLayout issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/394729)

Answer (score 0):

In button, while clicking by applying the tap animation to hide your frame. So, you use the Label instead of the button like below,

```
<Label 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Text="Test"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        TextColor="White">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

For handling the click, you can use TapGestureRecognizer.